Getting 401 error for Jfrog Library in Android Studio for Gradle sync
I am using lib com.jfrog.bintray.gradle-bintray-plugin:1.6
in my project.
I am getting error 401 which is authentication error.
My colleagues are able to run the project without issue . I downloaded same code from GitHub.
The laptop has Zscaler and proxy settings is also configured .
The project uses java 11 and has certificates installed as per requirement.
What is the issue as I am unable to do gradle sync for this lib.

If the problem when doing gradle sync, maybe you need to check internet connection. Try to use your mobile hotspot.
